# Python: turns string into array

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code and am unable to append a variable that was a string, to an array to set of arrays
My code:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np

a = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191115_10_32_24_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 1
a_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(a)[0]

b = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191115_09_48_56_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 2
b_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(b)[0]


unknown = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191117_16_19_11_Pro.jpg')
unknown_encodings =  face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown)[0]




print(type(b_encodings))    # This shows that the variable is an array type
b_encodings = str(b_encodings)    # I make the array variable, a string
b_encodings = np.array(b_encodings)    # I'm trying to turn the string back into the array
print(type(b_encodings))    # It writes that the variable really turned back into an array


results = face_recognition.compare_faces([a_encodings, b_encodings], unknown_encodings, tolerance=0.4) # Here's the problem, it doesn't read it as an array and displays an error

print(results)
```

Comment: Adding the error you're getting would help others debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with numpy but here's my guess for what is happening.

1. `b_encodings` is initially an array like `[1, 2, 3]`
2. Then you set `b_encodings` to the string of itself which is `"[1, 2, 3]"`
3. You ask for `np.array` of this, but in the NumPy documentation it says this argument should be *array-like*. The string you are giving it **is** array-like, since

```
list("[1, 2, 3]") == ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']
```

So the final `b_encodings` is now this array of the components of an array as a string.

```
[1, 2, 3] !== ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']
```

---

I don't understand why you ever want to convert the actual array data into a string, only to convert it back later.

If you want to print it, it will probably get converted automatically to a string. If not, you can convert it inline. If you really need a variable with it as a string, you can create a new one.

If you need to store the array (in a file), you could dump it with pickle or write one line per item to a file.

Comment: I want to make b_encodings to string because, i want to save this in file

Comment: So... i didnt understand what you suggesting

Comment: You could use pickle to dump the object to file. Or write a file with one line per item. Assuming you can convert string items to their desired values, you could do `f.readlines()` to get the array back.

Comment: I need to replace " " " ?

Comment: I mean, delet the " from the valiue

Comment: You can't cast the array to a string and then a string to an array and expect it to be the same array. The reason for that is described above.

Comment: So what i need to do?

Comment: But i cant to use the data after that

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. My post above explains why what you're doing doesn't work. You've said you want to store the data, and I've said you can write the data to a file and then read it back again if you want more permanent storage. If you want to know how to do that, search SO or open another question. I can't see what else you want me to do to solve this question.

Comment: I understand what you say, but what should i write?